# Flutter animated Stepper

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation

I am trying to achieve the look displayed on the `Animations` package's site on pub.dev.

I included a gif on what I am trying to achieve:
[image]

I tried to implement this but am having a hard time as each `Step` is not a widget. I first implemented like below, but it makes the entire screen (including the vertical line) rebuild.

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: const FliAppBar(),
      body: PageTransitionSwitcher(
        duration: const Duration(seconds: 1),
        transitionBuilder: (child, anim, sec) => SharedAxisTransition(
          transitionType: SharedAxisTransitionType.vertical,
          animation: anim,
          secondaryAnimation: sec,
          child: child,
        ),
        child: Stepper(
          key: ValueKey(stepperIndex),
          currentStep: stepperIndex,
          steps: steps,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Any ideas on how to achieve the look that is displayed on the gif using a `SharedAxisTransition` from the Animations package?

Comment: i think both are using `Fadetransation with different duration`. Like using Random to select  durations[]. But according to UI we may, can avoid `stepper` and can do building custom widget

Comment: @yeasin-sheikh how would I avoid `Stepper` and `Step` while still getting the step layout? (vertical lines that connect each step on the left)

Comment: let's split the screen in 1/7  for left decoration and it will be stack[verticalLine, GestureCallback(AnimatedContainer)]. next part will response accordingly. it can FadeAnimation with column[...]  If I get time, I will share.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I need exactly the same behavoir